# Why isn't $C_v=\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right) _v$ equivalent to $C_v=\left( \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}\right) $?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, differentiation, mathematics, calculus

This might be a naive question but I just saw

$$c_v=\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V \approx \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}\right)$$

Refearing to the LHS as the theoretical expression and to the RHS as an approximation we can take experimentally.

Shouldn't both expressions be equal? The LHS is just the RHS after solving the ODE

$c_v=\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V \Rightarrow c_vn \partial T=\partial U \Rightarrow c_vn \int_{T_0}^{T}\partial T = \int _{U_0}^{U}\partial U \Rightarrow c_vn \Delta T = \Delta U \Rightarrow c_v = \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}\right)$

Am I missing something or are both expressions actually equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the RHS is also at fixed volume:
In general, $c_v$ can be a function of temperature and density (or other state variables), in which case: $$\Delta U = \int\limits_{T_0}^T c_v dT \neq c_v \int\limits_{T_0}^T  dT$$.

If the RHS is not at fixed volume, then the change in energy could also include work done by/on the system.

Comment: So assuming that $U=U(T)$ only changes with temperature then the equality would hold right?

Comment: @MikelSolaguren It holds only if $c_v$ is independent of temperature. Suppose $c_v(T)=k T$ where k is some constant. Then $\int\limits_{T_0}^T c_v dT = \frac 1 2 k (T^2 - T_0^2)$. It is a good approximation though so long as $\Delta T$ is small, and volume is constant.

Answer (score 1):

If the energy $U(T)$ at constant volume is a curved function, $c_v$ is the local slope of that curve at a given point.  $\frac {\Delta U}{\Delta T}$ is the slope of the straight line connecting two points on the $U(T)$ curve, an approximation.  Just like any derivative (local slope) of a function is approximated by (but not equal to) the straight line between two adjacent points.